# Seeking habitat data for UK

Tags: data-request, geospatial, images, uk, biology

I am currently looking to analyse the effects of habitat on animal movement and was wondering whether there is any freely downloadable high resolution (preferably <10m) habitat raster data (e.g. woodland, wetland, grassland etc) for the UK, specifically Devon?

If not, would anybody be able to direct me to a tutorial to create my own raster map of these features?

Answer (score 2):

You can access habitat data from web services hosted by the Centre for Ecology and Hydrology (CEH).

For example:  https://rip.ceh.ac.uk/lcm